# Receive API Response in c#

Tags: c#, api, postman

im trying to get a this value that i send with JSON string POST, when i receive the response in postman, there's value like status, id, etc that i not POST, while i do understand get the value from JSON string,
i dont quite understand to get a receive API value like status and Name

[image: Postman Result]

what i do tried recently

```
    public class Condition
        {
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string positition { get; set; }
            public int no_id { get; set; }
            public string time_auth { get; set; }
            public string account_type { get; set; }
         }
```

for the method

```
public partial class ResponseJSON
    {
        public bool Result(string jsonData, string URL, out string status)
        {
            bool resultresponse = false;
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";

            var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            string wrote = jsonData;
            writer.Write(wrote);

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            dynamic R = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(wrote);
            status = R.auth_type;

            return resultresponse;
        }

        
    }
```

and for the main

```
string jsonData = @"{  
        'auth_type':'7',  
        'staff_id':'1234567890',
        'staff_pin': '1234'}";
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        string URL = "Link URL";
        string status = string.Empty;

        ResponseJSON responseJSON = new ResponseJSON();
        responseJSON.Result(jsonData, URL, out status);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to declare the same class "Condition" on your client side, so you can deserialize the response with Newtonsoft with something like this:

```
var conditionResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Condition>(jsonData);
```

Comment: sorry for late response, turn out the problem is request.ContentType, i need to change it xxx-form, though , i havent fully understanding about ContentType